# finding allocated texture memory on intel

Tags: opengl

as a follow up to a different question ([opengl: adding higher resolution mipmaps to a texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349602/)), I'd like to emulate a function of gDEBugger. I'd like to find the total size of the currently allocated textures, which would be used to decide between different ways to solve that question.

The specific thing I'd like to do is figure out how gDEBugger fills in the info in "view/viewers/graphic and compute memory analysis viwer", and in that window the place where it tells me the sum of the size of all currently loaded textures.

For nvidia cards it appears I can call "glGetIntegerv(GL_GPU_MEM_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_MEM_NVX,@mem_available);" just before starting the texture test and just after, make the difference, and get the desired result.

For ATI/AMD it appears I can call "wglGetGPUInfoAMD(0, WGL_GPU_RAM_AMD, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 4, &mem_available);" before and after the texture test to get the wanted result.

For intel video cards however I am not finding the right keywords to put in various search engines to figure this out.

So, anyone can help figure out how to do this with intel cards and confirm the method I'll use for ati/amd and nvidia cards?

edit: it appears that for amd/ati cards what I wrote earlier might be for total memory and for current memory I should use instead "glGetIntegerv( GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI, &mem_avail );"

edit2: for reference, here's what seems to be the most concise and precise source for what I wrote for the ati/amd and nvidia cards: http://nasutechtips.blogspot.ca/2011/02/how-to-get-gpu-memory-size-and-usage-in.html

Comment: There is no Intel-specific extension for this purpose. That does not mean, however, that they might not adopt either the AMD or NV extension in the future. You should examine your extension string for anything that sounds relevant.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I did this yesterday night but couldnt find one on my recent test machine with updated intel drivers. I also tried both the nvidia and amd/ati extensions but neither worked on intel. However I'm starting to believe that gDEBugger doesn't actually have the information I think it does but instead uses "glGetTexLevelParameterfi" to obtain information and then derive from that, so the information might not accurately represent the information I'm looking for in the related question (if skipped mipmapped levels still allocate memory).

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do this but a program called gpu-z does this and is portable so I could use it to find the information I was looking for on multiple test machines. I'll let this question open in case someone can fill in the blanks and since it contains useful references. Of note is that I'm now sure that the total memory alloc sizes I mentionned in gDEBugger are inaccurate and only report what gDEBugger can see through "glGetTexLevelParameterfi", which reports unused texture mipmap levels as not being allocated when it appears they always are.